# Symfony2 project with Git : Best approach?

Tags: git, symfony

I'm currently moving from symfony 1.4 using SVN to Symfony2 using Git. I am new to Git and have read a lot of documentation since a week but, unfortunately, I am unable to find a way to work as I worked before with SVN. Indeed, I understood that the approach is different between these two SCM.

Let explain how I worked with sf1.4 and SVN. My repository structure was like this :

```
root    /* Main repository */
  branches
  tags
  trunk
    apps
      backend
      frontend
    cache
    [...]
    lib
      [...]
      vendor
        symfony    /* SVN external to symfony sources */
    log
    plugins
      sfThemePlugin    /* SVN external to sfThemePlugin */
      xxMyPlugin    /* SVN external to a plugin repository I develop */
    test
    web
```

In this way, I was able to :

- Load an entire project in my favorite IDE with vendors, plugins and my own plugins
- Able to update symfony, plugins and other vendors from their respective repositories
- Work on my own plugins and commit them without switching of project

Now I would like to do the same with a Symfony2 project and Git. The problems are :

- The Sf2 Git repository contains a 'src' and a 'test' folder in its root so my project repository cannot include the Sf2 sources as I did with sf1.4 without generating conflicts if I add some files in 'src' and/or 'test' to my project or want to update the sf2 sources.
- I would like my bundles to have their own repositories and be able to work on them, switch of branches, commit and push/pull without having to switch of project, commit and push the bundles source independently and then update my main project submodules.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a confusion.

As you are talking about a src and a test folder, I guess that you are using this repo : https://github.com/symfony/symfony and not the "standard" edition. In this situation, don't put the content in your repository root but in the vendor/symfony folder.

So you will get the structure you want by managing bundles and vendors through submodules.

Answer (score 1):

I was unclear about if you're already using them, or were just referring to "submodules" in the generic sense, but check out [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) for keeping everything together but being able to push/pull independently.

For your src and test problem, if you want to layer local changes into a folder, the best way is to propagate them through a local branch, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446583/undoing-temporary-changes-with-git/5447226#5447226).  That question was for temporary debug changes, but the basic principle still applies.